# What does the usage of `(void)struct_pointer`?

Tags: c

I am now reading a project and find some of the codes hard to understand, like below:

```
struct mcachefs_metadata_t* mdata_root;
...
mcachefs_metadata_release(mdata_root);
```

And the definition of `mcachefs_metadata_release` is as below:

```
void
mcachefs_metadata_release(struct mcachefs_metadata_t* mdata)
{
    (void) mdata;
    mcachefs_metadata_unlock ();
}
```

And the definitioin of `mcachefs_metadata_unlock` is as below:

```
#define mcachefs_metadata_unlock() mcachefs_mutex_unlock ( &mcachefs_metadata_mutex, "metadata", __CONTEXT );
```

Then, the `mcachefs_mutex_unlock` function:

```
void
mcachefs_mutex_unlock(struct mcachefs_mutex_t* mutex, const char* name,
    const char* context)
{
  int res;
  ...

  mutex->owner = 0;
  mutex->context = NULL;
  res = pthread_mutex_unlock(&(mutex->mutex));
  if (res == 0)
    {
      return;
    }
  ...
}
```

I could not understand what does the  `(void) mdata;` mean in the 
`mcachefs_metadata_release` function. What does the usage of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for suppressing `unused argument: mdata` compiler warnings. Rather bad practice, by the way.

Comment: @Christoph - Write a new function that does not take a parameter and / or get rid of the global.

Comment: @Hogan: that's only true for this particular case - there are valid reasons to have unused parameters (API design, necessity of a common signature, eg when doing polymorphism through function pointers, ...)

Comment: Two better alternatives: 1) Change the parameter name to a comment. You won't get warnings for unused parameters if they're unnamed. 2) Create a macro like `OK_UNUSED` that clearly indicates your intent. Use that so it's obvious what you're doing.

Comment: I think the bad practice is to warn about that.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, C (in contrast to C++) does not allow to leave out the parameter name in a function definition.

Comment: @Christoph - If any of those were true I'd expect a comment -- this smacks of laziness.